# Android progress dialog background

Tags: android, progressdialog

currently I have a progress dialogue on my application which have a fade Gray background. now I want dialogue with no background means fully transparent. anyone knows how to do this?

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>`
```

I have done this so far in my `values.xml`.

Comment: What have you done so far? Provide some code.

Comment: and I also want the size of dialogue is big

Answer (score 0):

Using Java:

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Using styles XML:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```